# symlink to a directory that I have just read permisson

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

I am trying to make a symlink to a directory that I have only read permission.

```
ln -s /archvie/someplaceNotmine somelink
```

I get this the permission error

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/archive/someplaceNotmine': Permission denied
```

I do not want write access. I just want my program to read some files as input. Is there a way?

Comment: Order matters.  Try: `ln -s /archvie/someplaceNotmine somedirectory`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I still have the permission problem though

Comment: That would indicate that you don't have _write_ permission in the target directory, the one where you are trying to create `somelink`.  Without changing directories, run `ls -ld .` and tell us what you see.

Comment: Also, note that, after you updated your command, the command and the error message are now inconsistent.  Run the new command again and copy-and-paste the error message into the question.

Comment: I tried absolute addressing. The permission did not change but I can see the links inside the folder. I putted it in bashrc while I am using several systems. I get permission denied whenever open a terminal

Comment: I am getting the same error. It is why I didn't update it

Comment: It seems that the linking is done even though to a place that you have just read access. Thanks @John1024
ls -l shows me that there are links there